# Browser choose wrong image from srcset for the viewport

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a responsive image code with `srcset` and `size` attributes. As the definition, **browser should select the most nearest small image to each break point**. I have following image sizes:

```
100x100
350x350
550x550
750x750
1000x1000
```

Here is my code:

```
<img src="image1.jpg"
     srcset="image1-100x100.jpg 100w,
             image1-350x350.jpg 350w,
             image1-550x550.jpg 550w,
             image1-750x750.jpg 750w,
             image1-1000x1000.jpg 1000w"
     sizes=" (max-width:319px) 131px,
             (max-width:479px) 208px,
             (max-width:575px) 254px,
             (max-width:767px) 346px,
             (max-width:991px) 350px,
             (max-width:1199px) 205px,
             255px"
     alt="image1">
```

As the `sizes`, for all the `sizes`, should load 350x350 image.

But browser load

```
350x350 image for 131px image slot (correct)
350x350 image for 208px image slot (correct)
550x550 image for 254px image slot (wrong)
750x750 image for 346px image slot (wrong)
750x750 image for 350px image slot (wrong)
350x350 image for 205px image slot (correct)
550x550 image for 255px image slot (wrong)
```

I see **a pattern between viewport sizes and loading image sizes** but as the `srcset` definition, **the pattern should be between image slot sizes and loading image sizes**. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was **DPR (Device Pixel Ratio)**. The browser will try to get image slot size multiplied by DPR. If the DPR is 2.0 or higher, the original pixels of the image slot will be multiplied by greater than 1. Then browser will select a higher size image from srcset.

If I need to check images with exact expected sizes, I should **set DPR as 1.0**

[image]